# How can I stop redis-server?

Tags: database, ubuntu, redis

I apparently have a `redis-server` instance running because when I try to start a new server by entering `redis-server`, I'm greeted with the following:

```
Opening port: bind: Address already in use
```

I can't figure out how to stop this server and start a new one.

Is there any command I can append to `redis-server` when I'm typing in the CLI?

My OS is Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, if you did not install redis via the package manager, and you installed it from source, then it might not work with systemv or upstart or systemd on ubuntu. Thus, the selected answer will not work by default. The second answer, which is not marked correct, appears to be more reliable.

Comment: Tip: testing whether a Redis server is running can be done via `redis-cli ping`. A running Redis server will respond with `PONG`.

Answer (score 858, accepted):

Either connect to node instance and use [shutdown](http://redis.io/commands/shutdown) command or if you are on ubuntu you can try to restart redis server through init.d:

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server restart
```

or stop/start it:

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server stop
/etc/init.d/redis-server start
```

On Mac

```
redis-cli shutdown
```

Comment: You can only do that if you set up redis that way. Kevin McTigue's answer works with minimal setup.

Comment: On OS X you'll probably have to use `launchctl` to do this, and on other systems, `systemctl` or `service`.

Comment: On some machines sudo /etc/init.d/redis stop will work

Comment: On modern Ubuntu, I just use `service redis-server stop` and `service redis-server start`, after having installed it with `apt-get install redis-server`.

Comment: This only works if you have redis-server running as a service. If it is running as a stand alone executable, then you will need to explicitly stop the process. Here are the steps I used to stop the process: pkill redis-server on a linux box

Comment: on WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux) ```redis-cli shutdown``` worked for me

Comment: Hi reader, be careful about the `shudown` command flushing your AOF persistence https://redis.io/commands/shutdown

Comment: (*) on Mac what worked for me was `brew services stop redis` - the `redis-cli shutdown` was basically a no-op.

Answer (score 229):

A cleaner, more reliable way is to go into redis-cli and then type `shutdown`

In redis-cli, type `help @server` and you will see this near the bottom of the list:

> SHUTDOWN -   summary: Synchronously save the dataset to disk and then
>   shut down the server   since: 0.07

And if you have a redis-server instance running in a terminal, you'll see this:

```
User requested shutdown...
[6716] 02 Aug 15:48:44 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
[6716] 02 Aug 15:48:44 * DB saved on disk
[6716] 02 Aug 15:48:44 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
```

Comment: Or don't even start redis-cli. Just send it from the command line via `redis-cli shutdown`. (you can send any command like this, for example `redis-cli set cat dog; redis-cli get cat`)

Comment: The only caveat to @jessebuesking comment is that if you've set up password protection, `redis-cli set cat dog; redis-cli get cat` changes to `redis-cli -a mypassword set cat dog; redis-cli -a mypassword get cat`, which can be annoying after a few commands.

Comment: @glarrain one thing you could do to avoid the redundancy is set an alias for your current bash session, for instance `alias redis-cli="redis-cli -a mypassword"`. This way you can make the calls like in my original comment without having to re-supply your password on each use.

Comment: @jessebuesking very creative! Wouldn't have thought about solution. For some reason I'm a little afraid of putting passwords in config files

Comment: @glarrain don't take my word for it, but I *think* doing this will only store it in memory for the current session (aka don't add it to your bashrc or bash_profile, just enter it as-is from your prompt).

Comment: @JesseBuesking, but the shell may remember a history of all commands that you have entered, just to you can use the "Up" arrow or Ctrl+R.

Comment: @SergeyOrshanskiy this is true. You could go in and delete that entry from your history if you'd like, but your password might still be written to an audit log if it's set up. I'm not a security expert by any means and personally wouldn't do this if you have concerns about security.

Comment: +1 to @JesseBuesking: I was getting "(error) ERR operation not permitted" for SHUTDOWN. Passing password using -a made my day. I am a newbie to Redis and was getting frustrated.

Comment: Can one similarly restart the redis server via `redis-cli restart` (or something comparable)?

Comment: @HassanBaig, no. `redis-cli restart` will report that it can't connect to Redis.

Comment: It is strange though that this option to shutdown Redis is apparently so hard to find (initially, also for me), even though it is rather obvious. That we need to start a `redis-cli` and then type `help @server` and scroll down in a long list... I expected that `redis-cli --help` would have mentioned this as well somewhere.

Comment: As pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704960/cannot-kill-redis-server-on-linux, this method does not work for everyone; my process kept respawining with a different PID. The accepted answer from @yojimbo87 is the only working method to stop redis service for me.

Answer (score 167):

`redis-cli shutdown` is most effective. The accepted answer does not work for me (OSX Lion). Thanks, @JesseBuesking.

Comment: yep, the accepted answer works only for Linux systems with Redis set up as a service in the depicted way

Comment: This also works on Windows. `redis-cli.exe shutdown`

Comment: As I mentioned above, it's a pity that this (rather obvious) method is so hard to find. I expected that `redis-cli --help` could have covered this case.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and get a failure: "(error) ERR unknown command `shutdown`, with args beginning with:"

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and `redis-cli shutdown nosave` did the trick.

Answer (score 71):

For OSX, I created the following aliases for starting and stopping `redis` (installed with Homebrew):

```
alias redstart='redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/6379.conf'
alias redstop='redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 shutdown'
```

This has worked great for local development!

Homebrew now has `homebrew-services` that can be used to start, stop and restart services. [homebrew-services](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services)

`brew services` is automatically installed when run.

```
brew services start|run redis 
brew services stop redis
brew services restart redis
```

If you use `run`, then it will not start it at login (nor boot). `start` will start the `redis` service and add it at login and boot.

Comment: If you installed redis using homebrew, `brew services stop redis` also works! :)

Comment: I would recommend using *brew services* now for handling the starting and stopping for the defaults. If you need a little more control then there are also other options.

Comment: This is the best answer as it works on all linux flavours and mac, including those installed using apt, yum , brew or downloading. Wether they have upstart or init or system d scripts or not. Thanks

Comment: I like the name of the aliases :) Cool!

Comment: what should I do if I want to restart and not shutdown @RayHunter

Comment: what should i do to check the status?? @doesnt_matter

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN redis-cli does not have a restart command. If you are on mac you can use the homebrew command `brew services restart redis` to do a stop/start which uses `launchctl` under the hood. You can create another alias that uses the commands above to do the stop and start. `alias redrestart='redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 shutdown && redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/6379.conf'`. You can also write a function to do it too.

Comment: Sorry for this confusion But `service restart redis_6379` restarts the redis, @ray

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN that is particular to your system and how it was installed. It will probably be different on different systems.

Comment: works for me. Thanks for answer in here stackoverflow platform

Answer (score 47):

stop the redis server type in terminal with root user

```
sudo service redis-server stop
```

the message will be display after stop the redis-server

```
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
```

if you want to start the redis-server type

```
sudo service redis-server start
```

if you want to restart the server type

```
sudo service redis-server restart
```

Comment: I wonder if this is still valid for new Redis versions if configured by default.  Issuing `service --status-all` won't show redis, hence any `service` command will fail against `redis-server`. But redis does show in `ps -ef`.  I just cannot find any related document.

Comment: Looks on Ubuntu 18.04 `sudo service redis start/stop/status` does the same, both go.

Answer (score 26):

Type `SHUTDOWN` in the CLI

or

if your don't care about your data in memory, you may also type `SHUTDOWN NOSAVE` to force shutdown the server.

Answer (score 20):

Try `killall redis-server`. You may also use `ps aux` to find the name and pid of your server, and then kill it with `kill -9 here_pid_number`.

Comment: This is great, works on mac / unix. (Mac tested, unix approved)

Comment: Bad idea to hard-kill a DB server. Always prefer a proper shutdown, or at least, kill -15  instead of kill -9.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy you should provide a link or somewhat of an explanation *why* it's a bad idea. Like how redis does delayed writes, so that there will still be uncommited data in memory.

Comment: @notbad.jpeg, of course, you can also drop your computer on the floor. If the table is high enough, this should also stop the server. Do I need a link or somewhat of an explanation as to why this is a bad idea?

Comment: With this method you're not thinking about the redis database state. You're using an OS functionality to shutdown an application instead of using the application itself or a daemon, which is probably using application functionality too. This solution is like unplugging the cable to shutdown the TV.

Comment: Redis has a whole documentation page on what Unix Signals it can handle. 

"The SIGTERM and SIGINT signals tell Redis to shut down gracefully. When the server receives this signal, it does not immediately exit. Instead, it schedules a shutdown similar to the one performed by the SHUTDOWN command."

Signals are given integer values. for most Linux systems, 9 is the SIGKILL signal, which tells the OS to stop the Redis process without allowing Redis to clean up. SIGTERM, or 15, does allow Redis to clean up after itself.

https://redis.io/docs/reference/signals/

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest to disable Redis-server, which prevents auto start while computer restarts and very useful to use docker like tools etc.

Step 1: Stop the redis-server

```sh
sudo service redis-server stop
```

Step 2: Disable the redis-server

```sh
sudo systemctl disable redis-server
```

if you need redis, you can start it as:

```sh
sudo service redis-server start
```

Answer (score 16):

Option 1: go to redis installation directory and navigate to `src` , in my case :

```
/opt/redis3/src/redis-cli -p 6379 shutdown
```

where 6379 is the default port.

Option 2: find redis process and kill

```
ps aux | grep redis-server

t6b3fg   22292  0.0  0.0 106360  1588 pts/0    S+   01:19   0:00 /bin/sh /sbin/service redis start
t6b3fg   22299  0.0  0.0  11340  1200 pts/0    S+   01:19   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/init.d/redis start
```

And Then initiate kill:

```
kill -9 22292

kill -9 22299
```

I'm using Centos 6.7 , x86_64

hope it helps

Comment: `failed: no such process` 

Answer (score 12):

Another way could be:

```
ps -ef | grep -i 'redis-server'
kill -9 PID owned by redis
```

Works on *NIX & OSX

Comment: @JoenasE, no, this should not be the accepted answer IMO. Having the OS kill a running process neglects the case that the application might have some data in memory not yet saved to a more persistent store. Shutting down the application _via a method provided by the application_ is preferably a better option.

Answer (score 12):

if you did **make install** (e.g ubuntu) while installing *redis* then you can do:

```
redis-cli shutdown
```

as pointed by **@yojimbo87** :)

Answer (score 10):

MacOSX - It Worked :)

Step 1 : Find the previously Running Redis Server

```
ps auxx | grep redis-server
```

Step 2 : Kill the specific process by finding PID (Process ID) - Redis Sever

```
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way could be :

```
brew services stop redis
```

Comment: +10 for this, it works without apology on mac!
this also works

™brew services start redis™
¢brew services restart redis¢

Answer (score 7):

If Redis is installed via snap:

```
sudo snap stop redis.server
```

Answer (score 6):

systemd, ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ sudo systemctl is-active redis-server
active

$ sudo systemctl is-enabled redis-server
enabled

$ sudo systemctl disable redis-server
Synchronizing state of redis-server.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable redis-server
Removed /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.

$ sudo systemctl stop redis-server
```

Answer (score 6):

Usually this problem arises after I shut down my computer ( or leaving running ) an irregular way.. I believe the port gets stuck open, while the process stops but continues to be bound to the previous port.

9/10 times the fix can be:

```
$ ps aux | grep redis

-> MyUser 2976  0.0  0.0  2459704    320   ??  S    Wed01PM   0:29.94 redis-server *:6379

$ kill 2976

$ redis-server
```

Good to go.

Answer (score 6):

If you know on which port(default:6379) your redis server is running you can go with **option 1** or you can check your redis process and you can kill with **option 2**

**option 1:**
Kill process on  port:

```
check     : sudo lsof -t -i:6379
kill      : sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:6379`
```

**option 2:**
Find the previously Running Redis Server:

```
 ps auxx | grep redis-server
```

Kill the specific process by finding PID (Process ID) - Redis Sever

```
kill -9 PID
```

Now start your redis server with

```
redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know on what port it would be running(by default it would be 6379), you can use below command to get the pid of the process using that port and then can execute kill command for the same pid.

```
sudo lsof -i : <port> | awk '{print $2}'
```

the above command will give you pid.

kill `<pid>`;

This would shutdown your server.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running redis in a docker container, none of the present answers will help. You have to stop redis container. Otherwise, redis process will keep respawning.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    PORTS                             
e1c008ab04a2        bitnami/redis:4.0.8-r0   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp

$ docker stop e1c008ab04a2
e1c008ab04a2
```

Answer (score 4):

Following worked for me on MAC

```
 ps aux | grep 'redis-server' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was:

```
/etc/init.d/redismaster stop
/etc/init.d/redismaster start
```

To find out what is your service name, you can run:

```
sudo updatedb
locate redis
```

And it will show you every Redis files in your system.

Answer (score 3):

To stop redis server

```
sudo service redis-server stop
```

and check the status of it using

```
sudo service redis-server status
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically for redis, but for servers in general:

What OS or distribution?  Often there will be a stop or /etc/init.d/... command that will be able to look up the existing pid in a pid file.

You can look up what process is already bound to the port with `sudo netstat -nlpt` (linux options; other netstat flavors will vary) and signal it to stop.  I would *not* use `kill -9` on a running server unless there really is no other signal or method to shut it down.

Answer (score 1):

The commands below works for me on **Ubuntu Server**

```
$ service /etc/init.d/redis_6379 stop
$ service /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start
$ service /etc/init.d/redis_6379 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Redis has configuration parameter `pidfile` (e.g. /etc/redis.conf - check [redis source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L227)), for example:

```
# If a pid file is specified, Redis writes it where specified at startup
# and removes it at exit.
#
# When the server runs non daemonized, no pid file is created if none is
# specified in the configuration. When the server is daemonized, the pid file
# is used even if not specified, defaulting to "/var/run/redis.pid".
#
pidfile /var/run/redis.pid
```

If it is set or could be set, instead of searching for process id (pid) by using `ps + grep` something like this could be used:

```
kill $(cat /var/run/redis.pid)
```

If required one can make *redis stop script* like this (adapted [default redis 5.0 init.d script in redis source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/utils/redis_init_script#L31)):

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/redis.pid
if [ ! -f $PIDFILE ]
then
    echo "$PIDFILE does not exist, process is not running"
else
    PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
    echo "Stopping ..."
    kill $PID
    while [ -x /proc/${PID} ]
    do
        echo "Waiting for Redis to shutdown ..."
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "Redis stopped"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The service name of redis is `redis-server`, so you can disable and stop redis with this command:

```
sudo systemctl disable redis-server 
sudo systemctl stop redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

On MacOSX,

This is what worked for me

```
/etc/init.d/redis restart

/etc/init.d/redis stop

/etc/init.d/redis start
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check if the redis commands are not working for you is if your redis-server.pid is actually being created.  You specify the location of where this file is in

```
/etc/systemd/system/redis.service
```

and it should have a section that looks something like this:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
PIDFile=/run/redis/redis-server.pid
TimeoutStopSec=0
Restart=always
```

Check the location and permissions of the PIDFile directory (in my case, '/run/redis').  I was trying to restart the service logged in as deploy but the directory permissions were listed as

`drwxrwsr-x  2 redis    redis      40 Jul 20 17:37 redis`

If you need a refresher on linux permissions, [check this out](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).   But the problem was I was executing the restart as my deploy user which the permissions above are r-x, not allowing my user to write to the PIDFile directory.

Once I realized that, I logged in using root, reran the restart command on the redis (`service redis restart`) and everything worked.  That was a headache but hopefully this saves someone a little time.

Answer (score 0):

To gracefully shutdown specific instances with passwords and not resorting to brute-force `kill` commands, use:

`redis-cli -p <port> -a <pass> shutdown`

```
root@machine:~# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       105  0.1  0.0  60552 10772 ?        Ssl  23:27   0:02 redis-server 127.0.0.1:10002
root       111  0.1  0.0  60552 10900 ?        Ssl  23:28   0:02 redis-server 127.0.0.1:10003
root       117  0.1  0.0  60552 10872 ?        Ssl  23:28   0:02 redis-server 127.0.0.1:10004

root@machine:~# redis-cli -p 10002 -a mypassword shutdown
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.

root@machine:~# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       111  0.1  0.0  60552 10900 ?        Ssl  23:28   0:02 redis-server 127.0.0.1:10003
root       117  0.1  0.0  60552 10872 ?        Ssl  23:28   0:02 redis-server 127.0.0.1:10004

root@machine:~#
```

Having a ton of instances warrants writing a batch script to loop through them all for a master shutdown.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code:

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'redis' | awk '{print $2}')
```