# redis - kill redis-server in google cloud platform

Tags: redis, google-compute-engine

I am playing around `Google Cloud Platform` and `Redis`. But is is way more complicated than I expect.

I want to shutdown `redis-server`, in my local version i can just:

```
redis-cli shutdown
redis-cli ping // Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

that means the `redis-server` no longer running.

But I cannot do that in `GCP`. I still can get `PONG` after the `refis-cli shutdown`.

I googled around and somebody suggest `kill`.

first find out what is the `PID` of the `redis-server`

```
ps -f -u redis
```

I will get:
[image]

which `1637` is the `PID`. so I do:

```
sudo kill 1637
```

and try `refis-cli ping` again, I still get `PONG`.

I tried `ps -f -u redis` again. I get:
[image]

It seems like for every kill, it will respawn it self with other `PID`.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redis-cli shutdown` works on Mac OS. If you using Debian or Ubuntu, the easiest, way you can shutdown the server is to go into the server and type `sudo service redis-server stop` **and** `service redis-server start` to start it again.

**Example**

```
test-user@my-server:~$ sudo service redis-server stop
test-user@my-server:~$ ps -f -u redis
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
test-user@my-server:~$
```

The question was answered in this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910378/how-can-i-stop-redis-server). You may also see the following community tutorial on ["How to Set Up Redis on Google Compute Engine"](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-redis)

Comment: thanks. I did actually setting up follow the link you posted.